# Exclude libraries that are marked as Provided using the sbt-osgi plugin

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-osgi

Using the [sbt-osgi](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-osgi) plugin, one can create 'fat jars' by using the `OsgiKeys.embeddedJars` attribute.

For example the following code (extracted from this [test](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-osgi/blob/master/src/sbt-test/sbt-osgi/test-04-embeddedJars/build.sbt)) embedds every dependency with a name starting with `jUnit` into the compiled jar:

```scala
OsgiKeys.embeddedJars := (Keys.externalDependencyClasspath in Compile).value map (_.data) filter (
  _.getName startsWith "junit")
```

In my case I have dependencies declared as follows:

```scala
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.logging.log4j" % "log4j-api" % "2.7" % Provided
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % akkaVersion
```

I would like every library to be embedded into the fat jar except for the ones annoated with `Provided`. So in this case `com.typesafe.akka` should be included in the fat jar while `org.apache.logging.log4j` should not be compiled into the jar.

Is there any way to modify the filter method above so that it fulfills my requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to achieve what I wanted:

```scala
OsgiKeys.embeddedJars := (Keys.externalDependencyClasspath in Compile).value.map(_.data).filter(
  file => {
    /*
     * Find configs for file and return false if it includes "test" or "provided"
     */
    libraryDependencies.value.map(x => { (x.name.toLowerCase, x.configurations.map(_.toLowerCase)) })
      .find { case (n, _) => file.getName.toLowerCase.contains(n) }
      .flatMap {case (_, c) => c} match {
      case x if x.contains("test") => false
      case x if x.contains("provided") => false
      case _ => true
    }
  })
```